# The type name 'Ceiling' does not exist in the type 'Math'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a home project on developer edition of VS2015 and I am  getting an error saying that "The type name 'Ceiling' does not exist in the type 'Math'". Although I can see this property in the Math class, but it doesn't let me compile. I am not sure what I am missing here. I also tried to search on internet , but no help..
Thanks!!

Please find the code below: it's simple pagination.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FoodStore.WebUI.Models
{
    public class PagingInfo
    {
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }

        public int TotalPages
        {
            get { return (int)(Math.Ceiling)((decimal)TotalItems/ItemsPerPage ); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you writing your code in a class or namespace that you named Math? If so it's getting confused about what Math to use. Also, always post code when asking a question about code. You can't go to the mechanic and say that the car makes a funny sound and ask him to fix it without bringing the actual car.

Comment: Try using the Fully Qualified name : `System.Math.Ceiling(someVal);`

Comment: `Ceiling` is a method. You're using it as a type, in the context of a cast.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

```
get { return (int)(Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage)); }
```